# How to compare a float and a Size variable contents in cocos2dx?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Here's my **onTouchBegan** function. It is working fine, if you put some other code into it. For ex. you play sound on touch of the screen, or draw sprite there. 
Right now, I' trying to check where on the screen, does player touche?  Depending on that, ball will move up or down.

Problem : **location** variable is of type float, while **visibleSize** is of type Size.
          I tried 'c-style typecast', it dint work. Can anyone please tell me how do I do this? thank you.

```
bool HelloWorld::onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *pTouches,cocos2d::Event *pEvent)
{


   auto location = pTouches->getLocationInView();
   Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
   location = Director::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);

   auto _ball = global_ball;
   if(location.x > (float)visibleSize/2)
   {
     _ball->MoveDown();
   }

   else
   {
     _ball->MoveUp();
   }
}
```

Comment: A Size contains a width and a height. You probably want to compare against one of those.

Comment: Oh god ! I dint notice it ! Sorry ! Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Please post this as an answer, so that I can mark it as "answered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Size contains a width and a height. You probably want to compare against one of those.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that from following code:

```
        auto listener1 = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
        listener1->onTouchBegan = [](Touch* touch, Event* event){
            auto target = static_cast<Sprite*>(event->getCurrentTarget());
            Point locationInNode = target->convertToNodeSpace(touch->getLocation());
            Size s = target->getContentSize();
            Rect rect = Rect(0, 0, s.width, s.height);
            if (rect.containsPoint(locationInNode))
            {

                // do whatever you want to do on touch

            }
            return false;
        };
        _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener1, this);
```

I hope it helps.